# Trying to make my wireless adapter work

Tags: wireless, netgear

I currently have a Net gear Wireless adapter wna3100 i originally had windows 7 but now i dual-boot by the way i am very new to Linux please reply soon thank you

Answer (score 0):

if your using the unity version of ubuntu, type "additional drivers" in the "Dash" [circle thingy top left corner]. a small window will pop up, it starts searching for the drivers for you. but it takes quite some time. other versions [desktop types] of ubuntu should have a version of this program too.